What is the theological status of Radha for different Vaishnavite sects?
Obviously, she has high status for Gaudiya Vaishnavites - but it looks like Srivaishnavites don't set great store by Radha.  In fact, Srivaishnavite Acharya Sri Tridandi Srimannarayana Ramanuja Chinna Jeeyar Swami seems to deny her very existence:
https://www.harekrsna.com/sun/editorials/08-13/editorials10539.htm

Quotes from www.ChinnaJeeyar.org


ACCORDING TO ORIGINAL SRIMAD BHAGAVATHAM, COMPOSED BY THE GREAT SAGE VEDA VYASA, THERE IS NO CHARACTER CALLED AS "RADHA" AT ALL. THE MENTION OF RADHA IS AVAILABLE IN RAJASA PURANA LIKE 'BRAHMA VAIVARTHA PURANAM'. WE CAN TAKE 'RADHA' AS A SYMBOL OF DEVOTEE WITH SELFLESS DEVOTION. IN SANSKRIT "RADH" MEANS TO PLEASE. THE DEVOTION OF ONE, WHO PLEASED LORD WITH HIS HEART, DEED AND WORD, WILL BE CALLED AS RADHA. BECAUSE THE WORD 'DEVOTION' IS IN FEMININE GENDER, SO THE WORD 'RADHA' ALSO BECAME A FEMININE GENDER WORD. WHEN A CHARACTER IS PERSONIFIED THAT CHARACTER BECAME 'LADY RADHA'. HOW LORD LOVES SUCH A DEVOTEE AND HOW SUCH DEVOTEE IS MERGED IN LORD, IS SEEN IN RADHA-KRISHNAS. HENCE RADHA IS NOT REALLY A PERSON, IT APPEARS. THAT IS THE REASON WHY KALYANAM IS NOT PERFORMED TO THEM. IT IS DONE TO THOSE WHO WERE REALLY THERE DURING HIS PERIOD.


Ask this from RadhaVallabhi or haridasi sampradaya people, see devi bhagwat 9.50.13 which clearly states the importance of devotion to Shri Radha Rani

Radha is venerated only in Nimbarka & Gaudiya sampradayas. Other Vaishnava sampradayas don't venerate her. Hence they don't find any problem in denying her existence.

In the devi bhagwat it is said

कृष्णार्चायां नाधिकारो यतो राधार्चने विना ।
वैष्णवैः सकलैस्तस्मात्कर्तव्यं राधिकार्चनम् ॥

Which means Devotion to Shri Krishn is prohibited without devotion to shri Radha. Therefore, all Vaishnavas should sincerely and wholeheartedly worship Radha(9.50.13)
In the same purana Lord Narayana describes Shri Radha as follows

राध्रोति सकलान्कामास्तस्माद्राथेति कीर्तिता।
आत्रोक्तानां यत्तां च ऋषिरस्यहमेव च॥

Meaning
Lord Narayan says to Narad Muni: She
fulfills al the desires, therefore She is
known as Radha. And as for the words
spoken here, । am the sage myself.
Everyone have their own views I am just referring to the scriptures
